# Continuity and adherence

Tags: general-topology, analysis

For two topological spaces $E$ and $F$

Please how to prove that $$f(\overline{A})\subset \overline{f(A)},\forall A\Rightarrow f:E\rightarrow F ~\text{is continuous}$$

Thank you

Comment: What characterisations of continuity are you familiar with?

Comment: $\forall W\in \mathcal{V}_x, \exists V\in \mathcal{V}_x, f(V)\subset W$

Comment: That's continuity at a point (assuming you meant to write $\forall W \in \mathcal{V}_{f(x)}$), how about global characterisations?

Comment: if it is continuous at all $x\in E$

Comment: What is the _definition_ of a continuous map between two topological spaces?

Comment: I only have this two definitions

Comment: I find that hard to believe. The usual definition of continuity is that preimages of open sets are open. I'm not aware of any reason to skip that definition, since that is a _very_ fundamental property. One _could_ make that a theorem after defining continuity as continuity at every point, but it must have been mentioned. And there's an equivalent characterisation in terms of closed sets.

Comment: can make a prove with my definition of continuity ?

Comment: What's the definition of closure you are using? All points such  that every neighbourhood of it intersects the set?

Comment: yes!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $f$ is not continuous. Then there is some closed set $C\subset F$ such that $f^{-1}(C)$ is not closed. Call $A=f^{-1}(C)$. Then there is some $x\in\overline A$ such that $f(x)\notin C$. That is, $f(\overline A)\not\subset C=\overline C=\overline{f(A)}$.

Arternatively, suppose that $f$ is not continuous at some point $x$. Then, there exists a neighbourhood $V$ of $f(x)$ such that $f(U)$ is not contained in $V$ for every neighbourhood $U$ of $x$.
Call $A=f^{-1}(F-V)$. Since for every neighbourhood $U$ of $x$, $f(U)$ intersects $F-V$, there is some $y\in U$ such that $f(y)\in F-V$. that is, $y\in A$. That means that $x\in \overline A$, so $f(x)\in f(\overline A)$. But $f(x)\in V$, so $f(x)\notin F-V=\overline{F-V}=\overline{f(A)}$.